# On a Jenkins Docker : CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles"

Tags: docker, jenkins, cmake

I really need some help to build a simple project with Cmake with Jenkins on a Docker container.

I use jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11 and the Cmake plugin : https://plugins.jenkins.io/cmakebuilder/

But I get these error logs :

```bash
First time build. Skipping changelog.
Install from cmake.org [InSearchPath]: Unpacking https://cmake.org/files/v3.24/cmake-3.24.2-linux-aarch64.tar.gz to /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.plugins.cmake.CmakeTool/3.24.2 on Jenkins...
Install from cmake.org [InSearchPath]: Inspecting unpacked files at /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.plugins.cmake.CmakeTool/3.24.2...
[build] $ /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.plugins.cmake.CmakeTool/3.24.2/bin/cmake /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Patate
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Patate/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Build step 'CMake Build' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

It says Cmake is unable to find the build generator "Unix Makefiles" but I don't know how to install it on a Docker container. I checked in the Plugin Manager but it seems there is nothing. I searched for Ninja as well but it's not there either.

I don't understand why there is no proper step-by-step tutorial to create something that common as a Cmake build with Jenkins.

Comment: What container are you using and which packages did you install?

Comment: I use jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11 and the Cmake plugin : https://plugins.jenkins.io/cmakebuilder/ I don't use any package since it's not possible to use apt on the Docker container since I can't use sudo (right?).

Comment: EDIT : I've just read this documentation : https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/docker/ and it seems that it's possible to be root in the Jenkins container if we build the image with a Dockerfile. So it seems my mistake was to use the official jenkins/jenkins image... What a trap... I'll rebuild the Jenkins image and install Cmake with apt.